# gmap3 define cluster content based on marker attributes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer, jquery-gmap3

Here is my code with gmap3:

```
var marker = function(data){
            return {
                values: data,
                options:{
                    icon: 'img/my-icon.png'
                },
                events:{
                    click: markerClicked,
                    mouseover: markerMousedOver,
                    mouseout: markerMousedOut
                },
                cluster:{
                    radius: 20,
                    0: {
                        content: "<div class='cluster cluster-foo'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>",
                        width: 53,
                        height: 52,
                        offset:{
                            y: -72,
                            x:-26 
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    };
```

So I understand the built in gmap3 allows defining cluster content based on different marker size. In this case, cluster has markers more than 0 will be applying `<div class='cluster cluster-foo'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>`.

However, I want to define different cluster contents based on a `data` attribute.

For example, here is my `data` array:

```
var data = [
    { latLng: [], foo: 1 },
    { latLng: [], foo: 0 },
    { latLng: [], foo: 1 },
        .
        .
        .
]
```

If marker has `foo:1`, I want it to be classified under `<div class='cluster cluster-foo'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>`, and `foo:0`, will have `<div class='cluster cluster-not-foo'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>`.

So I came across some solutions, they seem to separate the `data` into two different data set, and apply their own cluster stylings. This won't work if you want to have a cluster that is clustering markers from both data sets. For example `{ data: 1, foo: 1}` and `{ data:2, foo: 0}` fall under the same cluster because they are close enough.

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: If you want to show markers based on a given categories (show only foo: 1 or only foo: 0), why don't you consider fusion table? Cluster is usually distance based.

Comment: Or you can declare several MarkerClusterer with the markers you want to group together in each MarkerClusterer object.

Comment: I will look into fusion table. I need cluster because I need them to be clustered based on distance. At the same time, I am also looking for styling clusters differently based the markers inside the cluster.

Comment: I don't think fusion table is really what I am looking for.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this? In my case I want to display another value/image of the cluster contains a certain value. ATM everything looks exactly the same and won't see the different markers until shown individually.

Comment: I was able to resolve this using google map api utility markerclustererplus defining my own calculator funciton.